# Where is the music coming from?

Tags: overwatch

I noticed this while waiting in a skirmish on Temple of Anubis. In the attacker's spawn area, where the player can change heroes, there is some music playing. It sounds like it's coming from a radio or a computer, and sounds like an acoustic guitar.

Is it in game audio, or from a radio source that I can't find?

Comment: Are you sure it's not one of Lucio's songs? Where exactly did you hear the music?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I think I'd know what Lucio's songs are by now. And like I said, in the Temple of Anubis attacker spawn room, where you can change your hero.

Comment: Well, I meant if it was anywhere specific inside the spawn room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The music you are hearing is coming from a tablet with Hearthstone on. You can find it in the back left corner of the room.

Comment: The easter eggs section for the map on [the wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_Anubis#Easter_Eggs) talk about the tablet as well.  I wasn't sure if that was where the music came from or not.